# Define a relation ∼ on sets by X ∼ Y if and only if there exists a bijection f : X → Y . Prove that this is an equivalence relation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across this question for one of my classes and I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Did you try verifying the conditions for what it means to be an equivalence relation?

Comment: Do the same things you do for every "prove ~ is an equivalence relation" style problems... check that it is reflexive, check that it is symmetric, check that it is transitive.

Comment: It suffies to verify that the relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation))

Comment: To avoid close votes and down votes, there are some improvements you can make to your question. Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for general suggestions on how to do that, with an emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) such as what you tried, where you got stuck and so on, and on [how to avoid an "I have no clue" question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: ill keep that in mind for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show three things:

1) If $X$ is a set, then there exist a bijection $X\to X$.

*Your task: name it*

2) If $X,Y$ are sets and $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijection, then there exists a bijection $g\colon Y\to X$.

*Your task: name one such $g$ for given $f$. Hint: Use that $f4 is a bijection.*

3) If $X,Y,Z$ are sets and $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$ are bijections, then there exists a bijection $h\colon X\to Z$,

*Your task: Find such $h$ in terms of $f$ and $g$ and show that it is indeed a bijection.*

Comment: I'm gonna try it and see how I go

Comment: I understood the explanations but just kinda stuck on the last one(transitivity). Could you maybe give me another hint?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

To prove an equivalence relation, you need to show that the relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. I will show one of these:

**Reflexive**

To show $\sim$ is reflexive, we need to show that $X \sim X$. So we need to produce a bijection $f:X \longrightarrow X$. The simplest is the identity function $f(a)=a$ which is both one-one and onto.

Now try to see if you can work out symmetric and transitive.